# Is the-Abaser a good translation for Al-Khāfiḍ, one of the beautiful names of Allah?

Tags: allah

According to the wikipedia entry on the [Names of Allah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_God_in_Islam) a Name of Allah is the following:

> الخَافِض   Al-Khāfiḍ   The Abaser  56:3

How is this to be understood as a Beautiful Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THE HUMBLER, THE ONE WHO SOFTENS, THE LOWERER